# 401 error in twitter streaming api hosted in Amazon EC2

Tags: twitter, amazon-ec2, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I have an set up a server in Amazon EC2 and I'm with an application to collect tweets using the twitter streaming api. My current code is programmed in Python using the Tweepy library.

The code executes completely fine in my ubuntu 14.04, however I get a **Error 401: Unauthorized** when I execute it in the server, which has ubuntu 12.04. Tweepy is installed correctly and my Twitter API Keys are the same and being used in the same way.

What can it be wrong?

Thiago.

Comment: Have you set your callback url appropriately? (same domain as the ec2 domain)? Is there a detailed error response that your get back?

Comment: My team mate has discovered that there is a problem with time zones. The time needs to be set as the same as where the server is located. As our application is being hosted in a server in Sao Paulo, I set the UTC to that time. It works perfectly now :)

Comment: Same problem here with time zones. But in my case the time on the server was only 5 minutes late. Enough for twitter throws an error message.

Comment: please self answer and accept this. This seems to a common problem and couldn't find it documented nicely elsewhere.